# Dax Calculation on distinct count of column based on 2nd column distinct values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

[image]

i need to calculate the distinct count of **panel names** based on distinct **vehicle no's**

ex: for 6073kxx vehicle -distinct count of panels are 7 . please provide a dax calculation for this. this is sample data I have more vehicle numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a measure to do the distinctcount on the other column.

Create a measure:

```
Distinct Count of Panels = DISTINCTCOUNT('your Table name here'[Vehicle No])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this measure

```
Measure =
SUMX ( VALUES ( 'Table'[Vehicle No] ), DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[panel name] ) )
```